# Nested output folder with makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a nested output folder structure to build an open source library. However, I have never used makefile before and have some basic questions.

After reading some documentation, I managed to create nested folders and all object files compiled properly. But then there are still some errors that I could not figure out.

**A simple makefile sample (modified from original makefile):**

```
SRC     = ../src/lib
OUT     = rtklib_post_proc
LIB     = $(OUT)/lib

OPTS    = -DTRACE -DENAGLO -DENAQZS -DENAGAL -DNFREQ=3

# For using lapack and blas
CFLAGS  = -Wall -O3 -ansi -pedantic -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I$(SRC) -DLAPACK $(OPTS)
LDLIBS  = -lm -lrt -llapack -lblas

all        : rnx2rtkp
rnx2rtkp   : rnx2rtkp.o postpos.o

rnx2rtkp.o : ../src/rnx2rtkp.c
    mkdir -p $(OUT)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) ../src/rnx2rtkp.c -o $(OUT)/$@
postpos.o  : $(SRC)/postpos.c
    mkdir -p $(LIB)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)/postpos.c -o $(LIB)/$@

$(LIB)/rnx2rtkp.o : $(SRC)/rtklib.h
$(LIB)/postpos.o  : $(SRC)/rtklib.h
```

**Output with errors:**

```
mkdir -p rtklib_post_proc
cc -c -Wall -O3 -ansi -pedantic -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I../src/lib -DLAPACK -DTRACE -DENAGLO -DENAQZS -DENAGAL -DNFREQ=3 ../src/rnx2rtkp.c -o rtklib_post_proc/rnx2rtkp.o
mkdir -p rtklib_post_proc/lib
cc -c -Wall -O3 -ansi -pedantic -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I../src/lib -DLAPACK -DTRACE -DENAGLO -DENAQZS -DENAGAL -DNFREQ=3 ../src/lib/postpos.c -o rtklib_post_proc/lib/postpos.o
cc   rnx2rtkp.o postpos.o -lm -lrt -llapack -lblas -o rnx2rtkp
cc: error: rnx2rtkp.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: postpos.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [rnx2rtkp] Error 1
```

Any guidance to solve this would be really great.

**Update with a small change:**

```
rnx2rtkp   : $(OUT)/rnx2rtkp.o $(LIB)/postpos.o
```

**Result:**

```
mkdir -p rtklib_post_proc
cc -c -Wall -O3 -ansi -pedantic -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I../src/lib -DLAPACK -DTRACE -DENAGLO -DENAQZS -DENAGAL -DNFREQ=3 ../src/rnx2rtkp.c -o rtklib_post_proc/rnx2rtkp.o
cc   rnx2rtkp.o rtklib_post_proc/rnx2rtkp.o rtklib_post_proc/lib/postpos.o -lm -lrt -llapack -lblas -o rnx2rtkp
cc: error: rnx2rtkp.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: rtklib_post_proc/lib/postpos.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [rnx2rtkp] Error 1
```

**Update 2:**

```
all        : $(OUT)/rnx2rtkp
```

**Result:**

```
make: *** No rule to make target `rtklib_post_proc/rnx2rtkp', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: `rnx2rtkp   : rnx2rtkp.o postpos.o`. The dependencies are wrong. They need to be prefixed with `$(OUT)/` and `$(LIB)/` as that is where the objects are being built.

Comment: Updated the question, Sorry didn't work, I am definitely missing something. Could you please add it as an answer with some details. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to understand why would someone down vote this question, that too without any explanation of doing so. That's just discouraging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rnx2rtkp.o : ../src/rnx2rtkp.c
```

This line says that `rnx2rtkp.o` *in the same directory as the makefile* depends on the source file. That's not the right location!

Also, add all dependencies for a file on the same line:

Try:

```
$(OUT)/rnx2rtkp.o : ../src/rnx2rtkp.c $(SRC)/rtklib.h
```

and remove the dependency `$(LIB)/rnx2rtkp.o : $(SRC)/rtklib.h` below.

You also need to update the intermediate dependency:

```
rnx2rtkp   : $(OUT)/rnx2rtkp.o $(LIB)/postpos.o
```

Then do the same for `postpos`. Be sure to be consistent in the use of `$LIB` and  `$OUT`.

Comment: thanks, I tired this, everything worked without error. But at the end, it didn't generate the executable. I will keep checking from GNU make manual and see if there is something I did wrong.

Comment: In your question you haven't included any command to link the objects files into an executable. Maybe that's what you are missing?